# regex match start and end with slash

Tags: python-3.x, regex, mongodb

i have this :

```py
dir1/
dir1/dir2/
dir1/dir2/dir1/
dir1/dir3/
dir1/dir3/dir1
dir2/dir1/
dir2/dir2/
dir3/
```

I want regex pattern that matches start with `dir1/` and end with after first slash `/`, result:

```
dir1/dir2/
dir1/dir3/
```

Comment: "dir1\/.*\/$" this should work if it is like js

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima didn't.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.
Also, see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
^dir1\/[^\/]+\/?$
```

It matches with your desired strings:

```
dir1/dir2/
dir1/dir3/
```